# NSNumberFormater worked in Cocoa, but not working in iOS

Tags: ios

In my Cocoa application I used the following to set a number format in a label

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter =
      [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
     NSMutableDictionary *newAttrs = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    [numberFormatter setFormat:@"###,##0;(###,##0)"]; 
     [newAttrs setObject:[UIColor redColor] forKey:@"NSColor"];
     [numberFormatter setTextAttributesForNegativeValues:newAttrs];

     [[datacellR1C2 cell] setFormatter:numberFormatter];
```

As I adapt the project to iOS, I get an error when I use this.  I get the error, “setFormat not found”

What should I use in iOS application built with UIKit.h?

Comment: It's confusing, because in this document: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003705 it is not there, but in some of the examples it is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `setFormat:` method is not available in iOS (see [NSNumberFormatter Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003705)).
Use the `setPositiveFormat:` and `setNegativeFormat:` methods instead.